# Recursive function of a list

Tags: haskell

I'm a little confused with that recursive function on haskell, can somebody explain me better ?

```
cut [] = ([],[])
cut (x:[]) = ([x],[]) 
cut (x:y:l) = let (xs,ys) = cut l
             in (x:xs,y:ys)
```

P.S. : The "let...in" part is confusing me a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haskell `let` has the following syntax: `let <bindings> in <expression>`

So you create some bindings and use that in the expression.

Example:

```
λ> let a = 3 in a + 3
6
```

The type of `cut` function is `cut :: [a] -> ([a], [a])`.

So, the function `cut` returns a tuple of type `([a],[a])` and that is exactly what is pattern matched in `let` expression of your cut function. The variable `xs` is pattern matched with the first element of the tuple i.e [a] and the next variable `ys` is pattern matched with the second element of the tuple which is another list.

Comment: Oh i think i might understand ! So the recursion is made between the let...in , right ?

Comment: @Damiii Yes, because that's where the `cut` function is being called.

Answer (score 1):

```
cut [] = ([],[])
cut (x:[]) = ([x],[])
```

These are the edge conditions, and

```
cut (x:y:l) = let (xs,ys) = cut l
              in  (x:xs,y:ys)
```

is the recursive part. In it,

1. pattern matching `(x:y:l)` will break that the argument list of `cut` to three part, first element of it will be bound to `x`, second element to `y`, and the rest to `l`
2. `let (xs, ys) = cut l` says applying `cut` to `l`, the result should be a pair, and binding the first part of it to `xs`, the second part to `ys`
3. the value of `cut (x:y:l)` will be `(x:xs,y:ys)` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I'll go through an example step-by-step, and hopefully it will make things clearer. First let me establish the following line numbers:

```hs
1.  cut [] = ([],[])
2.  cut (x:[]) = ([x],[]) 
3.  cut (x:y:l) = let (xs,ys) = cut l
                  in (x:xs,y:ys)
```

Using the following call as an example:

```
cut [0,1,2]
```

This matches the clause of line the 3. because the list has at least 2 elements. Therefore `x = 0`, `y = 1` and `l = [2]`. So it evaluates to the following:

```
let (xs,ys) = cut [2]
              in (0:xs, 1:ys)
```

`cut [2]` matches the clause of line 2. with `x` being bound to 2.

```
let (xs,ys) = ([2], [])
             in (0:xs, 1:ys)
```

We conclude then that `xs = [2]` and `ys = []`:

```
(0:[2], 1:[])
```

Which is the same as:

```
([0,2], [1])
```

So what this function is doing is splitting a list in two, by putting the even indexes in the first list and the odd ones in the second list.

Comment: Thank you ! 
I understood everything ! :)